# Position Image to the top of a div, using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an image with id.css:

```
#imgP {
  max-width:300px ;
  max-height:300px ;
  position: relative;
  top:0 ;
  left: calc(1em + 1vw);
}
```

and I try to position the top to his parent id.css:

```
#parent {
  top:-60vh;
  background-image: url('../Image/infome.png');
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: none; 
  padding: 10px; 
}
```

using JQuery

```
$(window).load(function() {
    y = $('#parent').offset().top;
    $("#imgP").css({top:-y});
});`
```

But the top set as a px number and not stick to the div top position.